# Scheduled job mail_report fails [500 error] when adding instanceId paramter

Tags: joomla, scheduled-job

Our scheduled job for sending a report fails when adding an instanceId. It works when removing that parameter.

We are on the latest version of joomla and latest civicrm.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What format are you using for the parameter?  It should be instanceId=12, for example.  Any additional characters like quotation marks or brackets will cause it not to run.  See: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/8584/105

Comment: instanceId=22 is the exact format